# How to sync data between several Raspberry PIs?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have around 5-10 Raspberry PI devices connected to the same network via Wifi. They run the same NodeJS code and have a MySQL database. I also don't have a central server that they can communicate with. Any of them can be turned on or off at any time they are not necessarily always online.

I'm looking for the best way to synchronize the data between them. Whenever some of them receive data I'd like it to be shared with all the other devices so if this mentioned device is turned off, another is able to serve all the data. Once this device is turned on again it should get all the data received by the others while it was offline.

They could poll each other via HTTP requests, but I have a feeling that doesn't scale too well as the device number grows. I believe there is a better way like some kind of P2P solution like Zigbee(It would be cool but it needs special transmitters and receivers if I understand correctly).

**Edit to clarify some questions:**

The idea behind it all is that I have a mobile application and whichever Raspberries comes online first, broadcasts its mDNS(raspberrypi.local) and the app always gets the data from there.

So it works perfectly well with a single device it's just "better" with more devices(you can put it in more places around your house and does its thing there). So it's not about that I am not able to add a master that is always on, I just don't want to because if someone wants to use it with a single device, the price doubles for them

But ideally, it should not matter which device the app connects to it gets the same data from any of them. Maybe synchronization is not the way I should go here and I just need another point of view from you guys.

Comment: is the data they are serving a sort of "virtual truth" that always represents the most up to date data? How would one of the devices know it has more data than the others? What if it went offline, which device would be "nearest the truth"? All without a central repository. In theory half could go offline while the other half continue to gather data. Then the second half go offline just as the first half come back and they have nowhere to get the most up to date data without something central holding it. I have an old pi as a NAS for this sort of stuff.

Comment: Added some clarifications in the question.